# What's the correct phrase ? " receiving gold medal in math subject or gold medal for math subject?"

Tags: prepositions

Which is correct?

> he receives gold in math

Or

> he receives gold for math

Comment: You can try googling for `"won a gold medal in mathematics"` and `"won a gold medal for mathematics"` on the web, in Google Books, etc.; and don't forget to judge for yourself, the writer is a speaker of what dialect of English, how good their writing skill is, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I see ***both*** being used in the context you want.

However, searching on COCA, I observe that *'in'* is more common when we talk about the 'subject (here, math)' someone won gold medal *in*.

On the other hand, examples of *'medal for...'* find more examples like....

> Her celebration of a second gold medal **for the week** 
> Terrapin submitted its first beer to the festival in 2002 and won a gold medal **for its Rye Pale Ale.** 
>  Mildred McDaniel Singleton, 70, who won the gold medal **for the U.S.**